# in-app purchase for auto-renewal subscriptions notifications

Tags: ios, subscription, in-app-purchase

I've been reading the various threads on in-app purchases auto-renewal subscriptions, and I think I've pieced together most of the information I need, but there are a few missing pieces.  I'm hoping someone can help me.

The situation:
I have various subscription packages the user can subscribe to (e.g., package A for £1 a month, package B for £2 a month, etc.).  I store the user's subscription information in my database.  When the user logs in, I check which package he's on and if it's expired or not.  My website, android and iOS all use the same database, hence this approach seems to make sense.

Subscribing users via in-app purchase seems straight forward enough.  I check paymentQueue and once the payment is cleared, I can update my database.

My questions:

1) My understanding is the user can use iTunes to manage their subscription.  Say, they go in to iTunes and cancel their subscription, how can I be notified so I can update my database?  Do I need a daemon that checks expired subscriptions to see if the user renewed?

2) If the user wants to upgrade their subscription from Package A to Package B, how do I handle the pricing?  Say on Jan 1st, they buy Package A, I charge them £1.00 and set the expiry date to Jan. 31st.  On Jan. 15th, they want to upgrade to package B via in-app purchase.  Ideally, I would charge them £2 for Package B minus £0.50 of credit they have for Package A and set the new expiry date to feb 14th.  However, Apple forces me to associate each package with a tier price.  How can I handle this?  I don't want the user to wait until the end of the month to put them on a higher tier package...if they upgraded mid-month, it means they want the new content package B will deliver to them immediately.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jason, Have you found any solution ? I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes you'll have to reverify your receipt check out the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html). They mention some important keys:

- `status` - 0 if receipt is valid, or an error code
- `receipt` - JSON response of the receipt
- `latest_receipt` (auto-renewable only) - base 64 encoded receipt for the most recent renewal
- `latest_receipt_info` - JSON version of `latest_receipt`

With this information, when a purchase is made, send the receipt to your backend for validation, the backend will keep the receipt in the DB and verify with status = 0 that it's a valid receipt.  From there, every `x` days you can validate that receipt with a chron job, daemon, etc. and reverify.  The response back each time will have `latest_receipt_info` that you now need to save to your DB so you have an up-to-date receipt for the next check in `x` days. This way you will always have the latest receipt. There is no instant notification for telling when a user cancels a subscription, but with this you'll know every `x` days if they have the subscription still.

2) Pricing like this unfortunately can't be handled.  It was not intended for a user to "upgrade" with subscriptions - each subscription is access to it's own exclusive content as of this writing. However, if a customer emails in and complains about it, you could ask for their user name and figure out in your DB if this user has indeed upgraded mid-month and reimburse them appropriately. Very old-school and not feasible for a big user base, but hopefully you won't have that many and can keep them happy.

Answer (score 3):

**EDITED**

For the second question, Apple's auto-renewable subscription system does not technically offer upgradeable plans **between different products**.

Every subscription is a stand alone product and it's up to the user to turn on/off subscriptions manually using the Subscription Manager in the iTunes Store.

However if package A and package B offer the exact same content only different duration than what [ajay_nasa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873864/2060669) said is correct, you can create an single auto-subscription product with different duration options. If the user is on 1 month subscription and then the user tries to change to 2-months subscription they will get the following error message asking them go to the App Store's subscriptions manager

[image]

So basically the ONLY place the user can actually change the subscription's length is in the App Store. Whether Apple decide to pro-rate the amount left on the old subscription or just append it to the current one is really up to Apple. You need to make sure the user have access to the subscription as long as it's active by reading the **Original Purchase Date** and **Subscription Expiration Date** field from each receipt entry and determining the start and end dates of the subscription.

Comment: That's a really bad idea and incredibly unreliable.  You should never hack in a subscription fee difference between two subscriptions because one day you may increase the rate for one and not want to for another and could lead to losing money in certain scenarios.  The best hack for the solution is to require the user to remove their previous subscription before upgrading. You can check against your DB if the user canceled a subscription.  Again for this scenario there can be a lag for the user, but infinitely better than this solution.

Comment: unfortunately, Apple's auto-renewable subscription system does offer upgradeable plans. Please try to add duration in existing auto-renewable subscription. You can further verify upgradation in itunes connect account of user who purchase subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Answering question 1, you can verify subscription receipts in the same way as other IAP, but you'll need to check it periodically to see if the subscription has expired (the verification will tell you if it's expired).

There is more info on the Apple docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]Actually, Apple's auto-renewable subscription system does offer upgradeable plans.

To achieve this we simply should add duration in existing Auto-Renewable Subscription. Every Auto-Renewable Subscription could be family of Subscriptions so whenever developer wants to achieve upgradation in subscription he should add duration in  existing Auto-Renewable Subscription with different productID.

Whenever, user upgrade his plan in between the month then his upgrade plan will be automatically works from next month.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question #1

Recently Apple launched a feature to enable server notification whenever the subscription is renewed. However, the subscription should be in-app.

See the links given below for your reference:

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b

&

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/news/45333106?sc_cid=ITC-AP-ENREC

Answer (score 0):

We Need to Check Cancellation-Date provided in Receipt.